# WebSocket Error in Play application on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, websocket

I've developed a play framework chat application where one user can communicate with other. All works fine at my local system but when i deploy the application to Heroku , i get this in browser's console :

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.my_product_site.com/chat' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0, reserved3 = 0
```

What's the mean of this & how can i deal with this problem ?

Comment: What tf `playback` tag means in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution : Just auto-ping your websocket after each 30-40 seconds